# Why am I getting a converting data type error when selecting a decimal column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to `SELECT` a column from a view as shown.

The datatype of the column is stored as a `decimal(18, 7), null`.

```
SELECT DecimalPercentageColumn 
FROM dbo.DetailsView
```

However when I try to do this an error message is returned:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Just a wild guess. There might be a `UNION` in your view that causes the error.

Comment: or a conversion on garbage data...

Comment: Either way, there's clearly non-numeric data in the underlying nvarchar field.  Take a look at the view definition and find the records in the base tables with non-numeric data.  Then you'll need to verify that it's actually invalid data and not correct data which the view no longer handles correctly.

Comment: Since you're on SQL Server 2012, you should be able to run `SELECT * FROM BaseTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(SourceNVARCHARField) = 0`.

Comment: or `DecimalPercentageColumn , TRY_CONVERT(DecimalPercentageColumn ) [Converted] ... where TRY_CONVERT(DecimalPercentageColumn ) IS NULL` from the source data

Comment: If you want the actual reason, you'll have to include the code for the view + definition for all the tables it refers

Comment: @BaconBits - Yes it turned out to be a problem in the view definition where there was an attempt to cast an nvarchar to a decimal.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check your view definition, It seems like when you cast nvarchar to decimal there might be a chance that you will get empty strings or character data in your nvarchar column. This might cause the issue.

You can try like this.

```
select case when isnumeric(nvarcharcolumnname)=1 then cast (nvarcharcolumnname as decimal(18, 7)) else 0 end from tablename
```

Comment: Please select my answer if it is really works for you